# Extracting data when cross referencing two column from different files and for each value print a new file

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have two files and want to use the pattern from File 2 to extract data when it exactly matches the patteren from column 3 or 7 in File 1. For example, I want to extract all lines from File 1 which has the value '5' in either column 3 or 7.
Additionally I would like if the data for each value in File 2 could be printed to its own new file.
All columns are seperated by tab.

File 1

```
... ... RNAME ... ... ... RNEXT
  x   x    3    x   x   x    128
  x   x   102   x   x   x     5
  x   x    2    x   x   x     =
  x   x    5    x   x   x     =
  x   x    72   x   x   x     7
  x   x    5    x   x   x    251`
```

File 2

```
 5
 72
 1040
 251
...
```

I have used `awk '($3 == "5" || $7 == "5")' File 1` to do so manually for specific values of File 2.

File 3 (what I would like for all values of File 2 as seperate files)

```
... ... RNAME ... ... ... RNEXT
  x   x    5    x   x   x     =
  x   x   102   x   x   x     5
  x   x    5    x   x   x     =
  x   x    5    x   x   x   1040
  x   x    138  x   x   x     5
  x   x    5    x   x   x    251
```

For context my file 1 is a mapping of sequencing data (.sam format) with about 250 million mapped reads (rows) and the file 2 is the contigs of interest. 
Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, so you mean to say you want to compare `5` to all contents of file1 once? and same for all lines 1 by 1 with all lines of file1, kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes, so I extract all lines of file 1 with '5'  in either column 3 or 7. And so on for all values of file 2.

Comment: still not clear, how values are changing in last column and other column? Please explain.

Comment: How many lines is file2 going to have? How should the output files be named? And what should happen if a line in file1 has values in both columns that appear in file2?

Comment: So the columns RNAME and RNEXT can be any value between (1-2737) and if they have the same value it uses the symbol "=" in one of them. The same value can also occur multiple times in the file. I am only interested in 160 of these values (they are my File 2) and all the lines they occur in. So I want to go through each line of file 1 searching for a value in file 2 (e.g. '5') in either column $3 or $7, if it matches extract the entire line.
I would like the output files to be named with the value "they are searching for". (e.g. "contig5", "contig72", "contig1040" etc.

Comment: If a line in file1 has values in both columns that appear in file2 I would like that line in both output files.

Comment: So file2 is going to have most 160 entries?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a ton of possible values to check, it's pretty easy to do in awk (Having too many lines in file2 would cause you to run out of available file descriptors when writing rows to the appropriate file(s), but 160 should be good) :

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { contig[$1] = 1;
                   print "...\t...\tRNAME\t...\t...\t...\tRNEXT" > "contig" $1;
                   next }
       $3 in contig { print > "contig" $3 }
       $7 in contig { print > "contig" $7 }' file2 file1
```